# Problem with inserting with sqlalchemy and DATE format

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, vk

My code give me this error with func "vk.profile_stats":

```
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")
[SQL: SELECT vk_profile.id AS vk_profile_id, vk_profile.friends AS vk_profile_friends, vk_profile.followers AS vk_profile_followers, vk_profile.audios AS vk_profile_audios, vk_profile.gifts AS vk_profile_gifts, vk_profile.date AS vk_profile_date 
FROM vk_profile 
WHERE vk_profile.date = %(date_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'date_1': datetime.date(2019, 11, 27), 'param_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I am sure that the input to the function is exactly correct. That func:

```
def profile_stats():
    profile = vk.users.get(fields='counters')[0]['counters']
    stats.vk.write_profile(profile['friends'], profile['followers'], profile['audios'], profile['gifts'])
```

Func "stats.vk.write_profile":

```
def write_profile(friends, followers, audios, gifts):
    session = Session()
    profile = session.query(Vk_profile).filter(Vk_profile.date == date.today()).first()
    if profile:
        profile.friends = friends
        profile.followers = followers
        profile.audios = audios
        profile.gifts = gifts
    else:
        profile = Vk_profile(friends, followers, audios, gifts)
        session.add(profile)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

The model for that:

```
class Vk_profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'vk_profile'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    friends = db.Column(db.Integer)
    followers = db.Column(db.Integer)
    audios = db.Column(db.Integer)
    gifts = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)

    def __init__(self, friends, followers, audios, gifts):
        self.friends = friends
        self.followers = followers
        self.audios = audios
        self.gifts = gifts
        self.date = date.today()
```

Comment: you are getting the error in filter query, use try-except to track the exact error

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your db? db.create_all()